# How to use regex to get only a single tab, instead of 2 and more? (grep repetition)

Tags: grep

I want to make a bash script in linux, using terminal commands.

I have the following text file:

```
[tabkey]text1
text2
[tabkey][tabkey]text3
[end of file]
```

Each of the above is in its own line, so there are 3 lines in total. The first has 1 tab, the 3rd has 2 tabs at the start.

If I use

```
grep  $'\t'
```

I get all lines with tabs, but not highlighted ofc.
So I ended up using

```
grep $'\t'".*"
```

to get text1 and text3.
However, how can I get only 1 \t?

I want to get exclusively text1, or exclusively text3. Not both. I ask this because I can't grasp my head around repetition, {N} to repeat the previous command doesn't seem to work even for letters, yet I need it for the tab character.

Comment: To complement my answer, (this is down to preference) you might like to try the perl regex engine if you have it available.  Just use the `-P` option with grep and you may find you have to do a lot less escaping.

Comment: Yup, basic regex isn't meant for complex stuff, I agree fully with this. If I knew about -E or -P, I wouldn't have posted this hahaha

Answer (score 2):

`.` matches all characters excluding newline `\n` so this would include tab `\t`.
Assuming all your `text1`, `text2`, `text3`, etc is comprised only of the characters in the ranges `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore) you can use `\w` to match only these.

```sh
grep $'\t''\w\+'
```

`+` matches at least one character which you may find preferable to `*` in your pattern as it won't match blank lines that start with a tab

If you want match more than just this, look at using something like this pattern which will match `a-z`, `0-9` and `-` (minus sign):

```sh
grep $'\t''[a-z0-9-]\+' test.txt
        -text1-
                text3
```

You will also need to achor your pattern to the start of the line using `^`, otherwise, your grep match can start anywhere (for example at the second tab)

```sh
grep '^'$'\t''\w\+'
        -text1-
```

Then, matching exactly 2 tab characters can be done like this:

```sh
grep '^'$'\t\{2\}''[a-z0-9-]\+'
                text3
```

With the perl engine (`-P` with grep), the escaping is a little clearer:

```sh
grep -P '^'$'\t{2}''[a-z0-9-]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above should work, but it seems kinda bloated.

Except the perl engine part, that is good. I ended up using extended regex with some help, because it seems basic/default regex isn't meant for this (hence looks bloated)

```
grep -E $'^\t{N}[^\t].*'
```

N=1 for text1, N=2 for text2.
^\t means start of line is tab, {N} is repetition of previous command, and while this works by itself, you want the further tabs to not be included (e.g. N=2 will include 3 tabs), so you want to exclude further tabs by [^\t]

Edit: Would flag this as an answer, but this site says I have to wait 23 hours lol